# Appstore проверка исходного кода

Tags: ios, apple, appstore

При проверке приложения для публикации в Appstore, производится ли проверка исходного кода приложения (если да, то каким образом, что проверяется), или же проверяется исключительно готовое приложение (нажимание кнопочек в gui)?

Возможен ли случай аппрува приложения (скажем калькулятор), который просит права доступа к контактам или сообщениям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос в целом - Да, код проверяется.

В общем случае, ревью приложения может проходить в 2 этапа:

1. Проверка ботом
2. Ревью "Живыми" QA специалистами.

Бот в общем случае смотрит на то, какие вызовы каких API присутствуют в вашем приложении. Среди всех возможных API есть некоторый список запретных. Например, Apple не разрешает встраивать в приложения функционал платежей в обход официальной платежки Apple. В подтверждении можно найти множество тем на форумах и английском SO, где разработчики жалуются на reject приложения в виду того, что в пакете приложения находились плагины а ля "XiaomiPay"/"SamsungPay" ([пруф](https://forum.unity.com/threads/xiaomi-iap-faqs.487225/)).

Еще один момент - Apple запрещает использование dylib в iOS приложении. Если вы отправите сборку на ревью, где будет присутствовать dylib - получите сразу reject и до запуска приложения на ревью дело не зайдет.

Касаемо прав доступа (например к контактам или камере) - вам придется указывать в самом Xcode проекте настройку, зачем именно вы используете то или иное право. Далее в дело вступает команда QA - если они сочтут при проверке приложения, что вы используете что-то необоснованно, то получите reject.

Есть еще такая практика - Apple прикладывает все больше усилий, чтобы большую часть ревью переложить на ботов и авто-тесты. По этому в некоторых случаях, уже сейчас, QA не всегда участвуют в проверке приложения. С большой долей вероятностью такое облегченное ревью получают приложения, которые уже есть в сторе, выпускающие обновления, где не добавляются новые покупки или права доступа